# Delete data from Firestore using Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

[image]I was trying to delete data from firestore, the fetching and adding data is working perfectly fine but when i try to delete data its not deleting and not even shows any error on console. Help will be appreciated.

My service.ts

```
userscollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
users: Observable<User[]>;
userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
this.userscollection = this.afs.collection('poetry');
this.users = this.userscollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => {
  const data = a.payload.doc.data();
  const id = a.payload.doc.id;
  return { id, ...data };
  })))
 }

getUsers() {
  return this.users;
}

addUser(user: User) {
  this.userscollection.add(user);
}

deleteUser(user: User) { 
  this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/${user.id}');
  this.userDoc.delete();
}

}
```

Component.ts

```
export class PoetryComponent implements OnInit {

user: User = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  content: ''
}
users: User[];

constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, public fb: FormBuilder, private userService: CrudService) 
{}

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
  this.users = users;
  })
 }

onSubmit() {
  this.userService.addUser(this.user);
  this.user.name='';
  this.user.content='';
}

 deleteUserss(event, user) {
  this.userService.deleteUser(user);
  }

}
```

User.ts

```
export class User {
 public constructor(public id: string,public name: string,public content: string) {
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably change the collection name to `users` here: `this.userscollection = this.afs.collection('poetry');`

Comment: Sorry, but according to me it wont make a difference because poetry is my collection name in database, if I change it to users it wont fetch the data.

Comment: `this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/${user.id}');` aren't you using `users` collection name while deleting?

Comment: `this.userDoc = this.afs.doc('users/${user.id}');` should be `this.userDoc = this.userscollection.doc(user.id);` I guess...

Comment: getting error as CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: ""

Comment: @WojciechJasiński  I have added the database in it, you can refer the structure.

Comment: I still don't know what are you expecting `this.afs.doc('users/${user.id}');` to return? You don't have `users` collection. Your users are store in `poetry` and their IDs don't start from `users/*`.

Comment: So where am I missing something, Please put a light on it, If I need to change something to make is work.

Answer (score 2):

Please update your `service.ts` file. According to this course https://fireship.io/courses/angular/ you have to fetch the document reference and then delete it. Please take a look on how it's done here https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-firestarter/blob/ebc7b2b8764459d57609fb4e79e3675d8f770ab4/src/app/kanban/board.service.ts#L60.

So in your case, you have the reference to users collection (I don't know why you call it `poetry`, you should either call it `users` in the firestore or `poetryCollection` in your code)

```
this.userscollection = this.afs.collection('poetry');
```

While adding me user you're using this collection:

```
addUser(user: User) {
  this.userscollection.add(user);
}
```

If you want to delete an existing user you should use this collection in the very same way.
Why don't you try to update your delete method to something like this:

```
deleteUser(user: User) { 
  this.userscollection.doc(user.id).delete();
}
```

- use `usercollection` that points to `poetry` collection in your firestore,
- get reference to the user by it's id,
- delete it.